# Associated object not saved with fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, fields-for

i´m a newbie to rails and have a problem with my associated object not being saved. I think I did everything the way it should be done and I can´t figure out, why it isn´t working. So thanks in advance for everyone who can help me get a little closer to solving this problem.
These are my models :

```
class Examdate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam
  attr_accessible :date, :exam_id
end
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :prof_id, :deadline
  belongs_to :prof
  has_many :examdates, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :examdates
end
```

In my `exams_controller` I have this:

```
def new
    @exam = Exam.new
    3.times{@exam.examdates.build()}
end
def create
    @exam = Exam.new(params[:exam])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @exam.save 
      ....
```

Now in my view I have the `semantic_fields_for` method, I also tried it with normal `fields_for` and got the same result:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @exam do |f| %>
<% if @exam.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@exam.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @exam.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>   
<%= f.inputs do%>
<%= f.input :title%>
<%= f.input :prof%> 
<%= f.input :deadline, :start_year => Time.now.year, :label => "Anmeldefrist"%>
 <% end %>  
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :examdates do |builder|%>
    <%= render "examdates_fields", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
 <%= f.buttons do %>
  <%= f.commit_button "Speichern"%>
<% end %> 
<% end %>
```

In the partial is this, will later be extended

```
<%= f.inputs :date%>
```

Now I get the form with the correct three date fields and I can save the `Exam` itself correctly. When I look at `params[:exam][:examdates_attributes]` the dates are there:

```
{"0"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2006", "date(2i)"=>"1", "date(3i)"=>"1"},
 "1"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2006", "date(2i)"=>"1", "date(3i)"=>"1"},
 "2"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2006", "date(2i)"=>"1", "date(3i)"=>"1"}}
```

But when I put `Exam.find(1).exdates` in my rails Console, I get `[]`. I really don´t have any idea what I did wrong, so every little tip is very appreciated:)

Comment: Try specifying which collection to be used in your fields_for: <%= f.semantic_fields_for :examdates, @exam.examdates do |builder| %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `attr_accessible` in your **Exam** model, I think you'll have to include `:examdates_attributes` in that list. Otherwise, mass assignment to the nested model will not be allowed.

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :prof_id, :deadline, :examdates_attributes
  ...
```

Comment: That wouldn't matter actually!

Comment: OK -- care to elaborate @syed-aslam?

Comment: Actually, that was it:) Thanks so much for that quick answer!